# bound element inside ngIf does not update binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a angularjs directive.
in this directive's template I have added an ngIf directive and within it I display an input that is bound to my directive's scope.

```
<div ng-if="bool"><input ng-model="foo"></div>
```

I noticed, after a lot of trial and error that the ngIf directive cause the model to not get updated when the input text is changed. If I change it to ngShow everything works as expected.

I am looking for an explanation of this difference

[I have created a jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/elewinso/WaFs2/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's happening because ngIf creates a new child scope, so if you want to bind to the same scope as the other inputs, we can go one level down with $parent. Check [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) to understand more about scope inheritance

```
  angular.module('testApp', [])
  .directive('testDir', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<input ng-model="foo"><input ng-model="foo">' +
         '<div ng-if="bool"><input ng-model="$parent.foo"></div>',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.foo = "bar";
        scope.bool = true;       
      }
    }
  });
```

Take a look to new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSWVE/)

Answer (score 21):

This happens because you use a primitive on the scope.

`ngIf` creates a new child scope and it shadows the value from the parent scope.

#### Use the dot notation instead:

```
<div ng-if="bool"><input ng-model="data.foo"></div>
```

---

#### From [Understanding Scopes wiki:](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope.
>
> It doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens is that **the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name**. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works.
>
> New AngularJS developers often do not realize that **ng-repeat, ng-switch, ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes**, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved.
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always [have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m).

Comment: Thank you. This is better that using $parent reference in the data model, as that would be more of a workaround. When the angular wiki tell us to always have a `.` in data model, this is what we should do. In the same wiki, it also says that you can use `$parent.parentScopeProperty` as a ***workaround***.

Answer (score 2):

Define foo as an object with properties. This all has to do with javascript prototypical inheritance. See your modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSWVE/).

```
 angular.module('testApp', [])
  .controller('MyController',function($scope){
      $scope.foo = {bool: true};
  })
  .directive('testDir', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<input ng-model="foo.x"><input ng-model="foo.x"><div ng-if="foo.bool"><br/>changing me does not update the other inputs because i am in an ngIf if in ngShow all works just fine<input ng-model="foo.x"></div>',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.foo.x = "bar";
        scope.foo.bool = true;       
      }
    }
  });
```

For a detailed info see this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc).