# Directive - controller data binding in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm struggling with this for hours now.

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude>Hello World</div>',
        link: function(scope) {

        }
    }
});

testApp.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = "";
});
```

Here's JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2bKPj/

Now, all I need is for an input embedded in  directive to be able to reflect user model directly in testCtrl controller. 
I'm confused on how this beast works since I taught that scopes are shared in this case, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngTransclude` creates a new child scope which protorypically inherits from it's parent scope.

When you use a primitive on the child scope it shadows the parent scope's variable.

It's been already said thousand times: **use the dot notation!**

**controller:**

```
testApp.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = { user : "Hello World" };
});
```

**html:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.user"/><br />
Directive model:<span>{{ data.user }}</span>
```

#### Check my other answers for description:

- [bound element inside ngIf does not update binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512182/bound-element-inside-ngif-does-not-update-binding/21512751#21512751)
- [Directives inside ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369730/directives-inside-ng-include/21370418#21370418)